# Transmit NSMenu commands to the current window?

Tags: cocoa, macos

Newbie OS X developer here, although fairly experienced with iOS.

I am missing something basic about the way the top-level NSMenu interacts with the application.  I want the File->Save command to go to the current window.  So far I have only been able to receive NSMenu actions in the app delegate.  Am I supposed to keep track of the active window there and invoke methods from the app delegate?

Comment: Do you want the window to perform the method?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, it sounds like you need to [read up](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/MenuList.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000032-SW1) on Mac menu handling, because there are a lot of things you need to know about in order to deal with menus correctly.

To answer your specific question, if a menu item has a target of `nil`, such as the `Save` menu item, then the menu handling system walks up the responder chain, starting from the currently active control or view (first responder), looking for an object that implements the action selector for that menu item.

If you don't understand how the responder chain works, you should [read about that too](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html), because it's fundamental to understanding how Mac apps work.

If you want your window controller to handle the `‑save:` action when its window is the main window, then all you need to do is implement the `‑save:` action in your window controller. Because the window controller is in the responder chain before the application delegate, its implementation of the method will be used.